# What is Domain Model in a MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When following a book on asp.net MVC I have found this phrase “Domain Model”. The author of the book states,

“MVC Framework projects start with the domain model because everything in an MVC Framework application revolves around it”.

How? Does this has anything to do with MVC model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what they mean but here is my guess.

One of the purposes with MVC (the pattern) is to remove coupling between the user interface and the business logic. That is achieved thanks to the controller which acts as an bridge between the business logic and the view (UI).

But to complicate things ASP.NET have also introduced view models which is a proxy between the business entity and the view. It allows us to do model specializations (i.e. encode HTML entities etc) without having to pollute the business entity.

There is a practice called Domain Driven Design which is used to reduce complexity in applications where the business logic contains a lot of rules that have to be followed. In it, the encapsulation of those business rules are called a Domain model.

So what the book probably is saying is that you can start with the business layer and then use ASP.NET MVC to build the UI around it without creating hard coupling between the business and the UI application (ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Special thanks for using “Domain Driven Design”, it explains the whole thing. Additionally, I like the idea of the view model, it helps to achieve better separation of concern.